# Api Requests with Ruby gem Typhoeus

Tags: ruby, api, httparty, typhoeus

What is wrong with the following request?

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/groups",
                                    method: :get,
                                    userpwd: "test_user:test_password",
                                    headers: { 'ContentType' => "application/json"})
response = request.body
puts response
```

This returns `undefined method body for #<Typhoeus::Request:0x007f8e50d3b1d0> (NoMethodError)`

The following request works fine with `httparty`:

```
call= "/api/v2/groups/"
auth = {:username => "test_user", :password => "test_password"}
url = HTTParty.get("http://fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/groups",
                   :basic_auth => auth,
                   :headers => { 'ContentType' => 'application/json' } )
response = url.body
puts response
```

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
response = request.response
puts response.body
```

with no luck. I receive this : `undefined method body for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus

You need to do the get before the response body is available.

EDIT: Here is an operable solution.  It doesn't use your website, which I couldn't access even manually.  But, this returns response code 200 and the response_body.  Running this in my debugger showed the complete response, which you could see using "puts response.inspect".

```
class TyphoeusTry
  require 'typhoeus'
  request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://www.google.com",
                                  method: :get,
                                  userpwd: "test_user:test_password",
                                  headers: { ContentType: "application/json"})
  response = request.run
  puts response.response_body
end
```

Comment: Head slap... Okay, so you have to get a response before you get the body, of course.  Were there any log messages regarding the request.response?  I expected the response method to return either a hash or the integer value of the HTTP error, not nil.  Also, I am going to do some research and will come back...

Comment: I'm not seeing any other error messages. What's happening is `request.response` is coming back nil, returning no information. I can't really find the http error code. With httparty I would do `puts url.code` to get the code, but I can't seem to figure out how to get that value with typhoeus.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't actually execute your request. The following code should work.

```
request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://fluidsurveys.com/api/v2/groups",
                                method: :get,
                                userpwd: "test_user:test_password",
                                headers: { 'ContentType' => "application/json"})

request.run
response = request.response
response_code = response.code
response_body = response.body
```